# Any reason why Mage::registry('current_category') would return NULL?

Tags: magento

I am using a template which calls a function in block, and inside that block I am trying to pull a current category with `Mage::registry('current_category')`. However it always returns NULL. I've tried doing this from product page, search page - still nothing. Is there any reason why it would return NULL, what are some things I could check?

Comment: you could chekc with debugger where this is set and where it gets unset

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's null because it's not set.  The registry acts as a system for global variables that don't rely on PHP's built in global support.  It is not guaranteed that any particular variable that's been registered will be available on every page.  For example, you said you tried this on the search page.  What should the `current_category` be on the search page?

It's null because it's supposed to be.

Comment: Also the category will only be set for product pages if the URL contains the relevant category name.

Comment: @clockworkgeek But in my case on poduct page for some products (all without category name in url) `Mage::registry('current_category')` returns null but in other cases it returns the category object. Why is that?

Comment: I shall guess and say that if you look on the URL rewrites page you may find those products-with-categories are being rewritten to a path which includes a category ID.  And since I'm guessing there may also be something to do with cached values, that would be harder to determine.

Comment: so, how do we know if the registry is available for a certain page?

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$category = $this->helper('catalog/category')->getCategoryUrl(Mage::registry('current_category'));
```

Comment: :( `<b>Fatal error</b>:  Call to a member function getData() on a non-object in <b>...\Magento\app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Helper\Category.php</b> on line <b>100</b>`

Comment: ...and your template file is?

Comment: If the return value of Mage::registry('current_category') is null, then getting the category URL isn't going to work.