# how to forbid the Fatal error: Call to a member function?

Tags: php, magento

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Any reason why Mage::registry(‘current_category’) would return NULL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6264514/any-reason-why-mageregistrycurrent-category-would-return-null)
>   [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Fatal error: Call to a member function getParentCategory() on a non-object in...

the code:

```
$_category_detail=Mage::registry('current_category');
$id=$_category_detail->getParentCategory()->getId();
```

now, when the page can't use getParentCategory() i using the following but can't work.

```
 if( isset(getParentCategory()){
        $id=$_category_detail->getParentCategory()->getId();  
    }
```

why? thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `method_exists()` rather than trying to call a non-existent function:

```
if (method_exists($_category_detail, "getParentCategory"))
```

Comment: Doesn't it trigger an error if `$_category_detail` is not a valid object?

Comment: It won't - Just tested it myself... Neither documentation nor test metion or trigger an error ;) Just returns `false`

Answer (score 4):

It appears that `$_category_detail` is not an object. Therefore `Mage::registry('current_category')` is not returning an object.

It's most likely returning some sort of `NULL` or `false` value upon fail. And PHP is making you notice that `(NULL)->getParentCategory()` is meaningless.

In your particular case it returns NULL because `current_category` is not set in your registry.

Answer (score 1):

isset() only checks for member variables. Use method_exists().

PHP Manual: http://php.net/manual/de/function.method-exists.php

```
if (method_exists($_category_detail, 'getParentCategory')) {
    $id = $_category_detail->getParentCategory()->getId()
}
```