# why Mage::registry('current_category') returning NULL?

Tags: error-handling, magento-1.9

I copied the whole working website to another domain. 
Cleared all data like categories, order everything

Reindexed the store now when i created everything again as per new requirements but no products are shown on the list page.

is it due to URL rewrite as I copied the database also.

Comment: Did you check the Stock Availability for products?? or clear cache

Comment: Yes all are updates they are in stock with some quantity

Comment: Did you check Visibility and Status?

Comment: please refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6264514/any-reason-why-mageregistrycurrent-category-would-return-null
or check the log file

Comment: Yes these things are checked many times.

Comment: did you get any error in log?

Comment: No error for this in log nor in console.

Comment: Can it be happen due to URL rewrite as this site is a copy of another website.

Comment: If you think it is due to URL rewrite than do the following 1. change the mode "Update on Save" of Catalog URL Rewrites in index management 2.  than Update the product, hope this help

Comment: Update the product means

Comment: Catalog-> product->open product and save it